# Possible FET with SMD marking 2YJ33

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount, fet

I need to replace a SOT-23 SMD transistor with the marking 2YJ33 (image attached Q1 and Q2). Any idea what it could be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [CMBT3905](https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/640446/CDIL/CMBT3905/1) has marking "2Y" (the rest might be a date code or something). Can you check if it measures out like a PNP with diode test on DMM? (Pinout seems to match a PNP being used to switch B+ at least)